# Find size of checked-out code in current directory

Tags: git, macos, du, linux-disk-free

I want to find the size of the current checked-out files in a folder/project, but ignore the git directory.

Something like:

```
du . --ignore '.git'
```

Is there a way to find the size of all the files ignoring what's in the .git folder? When I do this:

```
du . --exclude='.git'   
du . --exclude='./.git'  # or this
```

Either way, I get:

```
du: --exclude=./.git: No such file or directory
```

What do I do?

Comment: I am on a Mac, and apparently the `--exclude` option doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason (likely the BSD history of the Mac's utilities), the macOS version of `du` does not include `--exclude`.  However, at least as of 10.14.x, it does include the much-less-obviously-named `-I` option which ignores items that are in the "mask" that is provided--in this case "mask" is just another name for some form of regular expression which at least takes simple `*` and `?` wildcards.

Running

```
 du -I .git .
```

gives the size heirarchy, and

```
 du -s -I .git .
```

gives the summary.  In both cases, the `.git` directory is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your `du` has no `--exclude` option, you have two easy ways you can deal with this.  This first one assumes that there are no hard-links between files in `.git` and files elsewhere in the tree, but that's usually true:

- run `du` to get the total usage
- run `du` on `.git` itself to get the `.git` usage
- subtract the second number from the first number

The second easy way is to install a version of `du` that does have `--exclude`.

There is a third way to handle this, which is also pretty easy but a little tricky: just move `.git` out of the way:

```
mv .git ../save-git
du ...
mv ../save-git .git
```

If you use this method, make sure nothing is trying to do anything Git-like in between.  Or, make `.git` a symbolic link to `../save-git`, or (if your Git is new enough) a plain-text file containing a redirect.  Both of those methods can mess with the total, but only by one disk-block worth of space (the symlink or plain-text direct takes a disk block, unless the OS / file-system uses in-inode symlinks *and* the symlink is short enough to fit in-inode).